# How to edit a question to be better focused without losing detail?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, deleted-questions

I am trying to learn how to address an issue between a team lead and a team member that has to do with ineffective communication. Ironically I was not communicating effectively about it myself, because [the question I asked about this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/96427/how-to-elicit-more-proactive-email-communication-from-employee?noredirect=1#comment292941_96427) got shot down.

It looks like I need to go to square one and learn how to ask good questions.

Using the question above as example, I am looking for constructive feedback on what mistakes I made, and how you would rephrase it to be a good question for purposes of SE Workplace. I have to say the feedback I received in the comments did not get me very far in understanding why the question was considered of poor quality.

Comment: The page link is showing page not found.

Comment: I've cast the third undelete vote. You can edit the question into shape to try to get it reopened and its current negative score improved. Note that there's much less activity on meta and the main site over the weekend, but I think you already got a lot of input recommending you to shorten it and focus on a clear core question. The amount of details right now is excessive and you should be invisibly updating the question based on comment input rather than replying to comments: we want questions, not play-by-plays. :)

Comment: @Lilienthal Thank you, I appreciate it.  Will give it a shot in the next day or so.

Comment: @Lilienthal I have just edited the original question based on the feedback, hoping it can be re-opened. Thank you.

Comment: @AO it's much improved now and I think it's answerable. I think it would help to avoid the third person and all the hypotheticals. A simple "one of my reports isn't as productive as I'd like and he's not communicating well about his progress" should be easier to comprehend and answer. You may also want to rephrase "what other assumptions to test" and you should perhaps make it clear that you're, as I presume, looking for ways to talk to this report about his behaviour and what kind of changes you need to see. Right now your final paragraphs still read too much like "how do I manage someone?".

Comment: @Lilienthal edited further to add information for accurate description of the issue and removing third person. Let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your question gets to the main issue: a boss expects a subordinate to do a task that all other team members do on a regular basis. Is there something special about this person's responsibilities or workload? Did he miss out on some sort of training or meeting the boss had with everyone else on the subject?

As far as details, I couldn't find any response from this employee as to why they don't comply. Do they understand the requirement? What are the consequences? Have you taken any steps to deal with this?

I understand what you're asking. I just don't see why this boss hasn't tried what to me are obvious initial steps. Either this person isn't capable, doesn't understand, forgets or intentionally doesn't do it. If you feel you've addressed all of this and nothing worked, your question may start to benefit others on this site.

Comment: thank you - at last a constructive response with no attitude. You are awesome. Your comment prompts me to think about the questions you raised, answers to some of which I had assumed but not verified as fact. Definitely useful for addressing the situation. Much appreciated.

Comment: I know responses seem harsh (and they are) and I've been guilty of it. Thank you for being patient and willing to work through it. Too many posts give up without accepting criticism even when it is constructive.